# Using Variable for Property Name of Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, variable-variables

saw a few answers related to this, but none answer this version of the subject in question.

Consider the following: (linkto: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cUKR/2/))

```
$(function(){

arrKeys = [];
objArr = [];

nameArr = ['name1','name2','name3','name4'];
descArr = ['desc1','desc2','desc3','desc4'];
allValues = {name:  nameArr, desc: descArr};

arrKeys[0] = 'name';
arrKeys[1] = 'desc';

    first = arrKeys.shift(); // returns 'name'

    $(allValues[first]).each(function (key,value) { 

        console.log(first); //returns 'name'
        objArr[key] = {first:value}; //the problem

    });

    console.log(objArr);


});
```

With console.log(objArr) producing the following array of objects like so:

[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
**first**: "name1"
1: Object
**first**: "name2"
2: Object
**first**: "name3"
3: Object
**first**: "name4"
length: 4

The issue is that I'd like the property "first" to be the value of the var first (which is "name".. So instead, the result would be:

[Object, Object, Object, Object] 0: Object
**name**: "name1" 1: Object
**name**: "name2" 2: Object
**name**: "name3" 3: Object
**name**: "name4" length: 4

(linkto: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cUKR/2/))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set variables as key names you have to use bracket notation;

```
console.log(first); // returns 'name'
var obj = {};
obj[first] = value;
objArr[key] = obj; // no longer a problem
```

Sorry it's more verbose :(

Edit;

In ES6 you can now use [computed-property-names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names);

```
const key = 'name';
const value = 'james';

const obj = {
  [key]: value
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = {}
x[first] = value
objArr[key] = x
```

Javascript object literal syntax treats unquoted keys as if they were quoted strings instead of variable names. You have to use bracket syntax to set properties with names computed at runtime.

(Why are you wrapping your code in a jQuery call? And you really should be using `var` declarations.)

Comment: I'm not using those global vars, just when throwing that example together for this specific question. The jquery is nonessential. Thank you for your response.